# Dropwizard custom AppenderFactory not recognized

Tags: dropwizard

I'm trying to implement a custom AppenderFactory for Splunk HTTP Event Collector. I wrote a simple class as follows,

```
package com.example.app;

import ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext;
import ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ILoggingEvent;
import ch.qos.logback.core.Appender;
import ch.qos.logback.core.AppenderBase;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeName;
import io.dropwizard.logging.AbstractAppenderFactory;
import io.dropwizard.logging.async.AsyncAppenderFactory;
import io.dropwizard.logging.filter.LevelFilterFactory;
import io.dropwizard.logging.layout.LayoutFactory;

@JsonTypeName("splunk")
public class SplunkAppenderFactory extends AbstractAppenderFactory{

    @Override
    public Appender build(LoggerContext context, String applicationName, LayoutFactory layoutFactory, LevelFilterFactory levelFilterFactory, AsyncAppenderFactory asyncAppenderFactory) {
        System.out.println("Setting up SplunkAppenderFactory!");
        final SplunkAppender appender = new SplunkAppender();
        appender.setName("splunk-appender");
        appender.setContext(context);
        appender.start();

        return wrapAsync(appender, asyncAppenderFactory);
    }
}

class SplunkAppender extends AppenderBase<ILoggingEvent> {

    @Override
    protected void append(ILoggingEvent eventObject) {
        System.out.println("Splunk: "+ eventObject.toString());
    }
}
```

It is said that we don't have to wire anything, as Dropwizard would scan and wire the stuffs automatically. But when I run the app, I get this errors,

> ./infrastructure/config/config.yml has an error:
>     * Failed to parse configuration at: logging.appenders.[2]; Could not resolve type id 'splunk' into a subtype of [simple type, class io.dropwizard.logging.AppenderFactory]: known type ids = [AppenderFactory, console, file, syslog]
>    at [Source: N/A; line: -1, column: -1] (through reference chain: com.example.app.AppConfiguration["logging"]->io.dropwizard.logging.DefaultLoggingFactory["appenders"]->java.util.ArrayList[2])

My app.config is as follows,

```
logging:
  appenders:
      # log format: <Level> - <Time> - <Revision> - <Environment> - <Thread> - <Log Content>
      - type: console
        logFormat: "%level %d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %mdc{revision} %mdc{environment} '%mdc{user}' %t %logger{5} - %X{code} %msg %n"
        threshold: ${CONSOLE_LOG_LEVEL:-ERROR}
      - type: file
        threshold: INFO
        logFormat: "%level %d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %mdc{revision} %mdc{environment} '%mdc{user}' %t %logger{5} - %X{code} %msg %n"
        # The file to which current statements will be logged.
        currentLogFilename: ./logs/app.log
        # When the log file rotates, the archived log will be renamed to this and gzipped. The
        # %d is replaced with the previous day (yyyy-MM-dd). Custom rolling windows can be created
        # by passing a SimpleDateFormat-compatible format as an argument: "%d{yyyy-MM-dd-hh}".
        archivedLogFilenamePattern: ./logs/app-%d.log.gz
        # The number of archived files to keep.
        archivedFileCount: 10
        # The timezone used to format dates. HINT: USE THE DEFAULT, UTC.
        timeZone: UTC
      - type: splunk
        logFormat: "%level %d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %mdc{revision} %mdc{environment} '%mdc{user}' %t %logger{5} - %X{code} %msg %n"
        threshold: INFO
```

How can i get this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might have to create a file named:

```
 META-INF/services/io.dropwizard.logging.AppenderFactory
```

In the resources folder of the project where the content of this file is the full qualified name of the Appender class (or classes) available:

```
com.example.app.SplunkAppenderFactory
```

The core DW project also includes this file with the default appenders:

https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/blob/v1.1.0/dropwizard-logging/src/main/resources/META-INF/services/io.dropwizard.logging.AppenderFactory